# Adding table rows based on JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm new with JSON. I have a select box and JavaScript `change()` trigger on it. I execute MySQL query with Ajax based on selected value. Query results will be printed as a new row in HTML table.

But the new row isn't appending. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<select id="orderAddProduct">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0001">Product 1</option>
    <option value="0002">Product 2</option>
</select>

<table id="orderTable">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#orderAddProduct").change(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "orderAddProduct.php",
        data: {option: selectedValue},
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("OK");
            orderAddRow(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
});

function orderAddRow($item) {
    $.each($item,function(index,value) {
        var row = '<tr><td>'+value.id+'</td>'
                 +'<td>'+value.name+'</td></tr>';
        $('#orderTable').append(row);
    )};
}
```

**PHP**

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . '; dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");

$productId = $_REQUEST['option'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products_view WHERE id = ?");
$sql->execute(array($productId));
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json_array = array("ID" => $row['id'], "name" => $row['name']);
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Comment: Is the `alert("OK")` showing? Have you checked that the variable `data` contains what you would expect it to contain (using `console.log(data)` for instance)?

Comment: Any errors in the console log? Is the `each` loop executing the way you thought it would (check by putting a `console.log` in it)?

Comment: @Anders, yes the `alert("OK")` is showing correctly. I just edited the code and added `console.log(data)`, please have a look at error message in my question. `selectedValue` is undefined index... What should I do?

Comment: It would help if you marked line 21.

Comment: @Anders, it was that I was using `$_REQUEST['selectedValue']` instead of `$_REQUEST['option']` which is correct. Now everything else (json) is ok but no row appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the master problem is that I didn't have `JSON.parse()` function in my code. Below is my finally working code.

```
$("#orderAddProduct").change(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "orderAddProduct.php",
        data: {option : selectedValue},
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response === undefined) {
                alert("undefined");
            } else {
                orderAddRow(response);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
    return false;
});

function orderAddRow($data) {
    $.each($data,function(index,value) {
        var row = '<tr><td>' + value.ID + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + value.name + '</td></tr>';
        $('#orderTable').append(row);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable names?

```
function orderAddRow($item) {
                     ^^^^^^----
    var row = '<tr><td>'+value.id+'</td>'
                         ^^^^^----
```

You define a `$item` parameter, but never use it in the function. Instead there's this mysterious/undefined `value`.

Comment: I just forgot one block of code... sorry - I'll add those lines to my question...

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
    alert("OK");
    orderAddRow(data);
},
```

You are missing out the returned value.

Comment: I think problem is in `orderAddRow()` function